# Simple complex math

Tags: complex-analysis

My textbook says
$$
-\pi i e^{i m \pi/2} \left(\frac{1+e^{im\pi}}{1-e^{2im\pi}}\right) = \pi \frac{\cos m\pi/2}{\sin m\pi} $$
and I cannot figure out the algebra between these steps. Thanks!

Comment: Hint:
$$-ie^{im\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{e^{-im\frac{\pi}{2}}}{ie^{-im\pi}}$$

Comment: Keep Euler's Formula in mind: $ e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\frac{1+e^{im\pi}}{1-e^{2im\pi}}=\frac1{e^{im\pi/2}}\frac{e^{-im\pi/2}+e^{im\pi/2}}{e^{-im\pi}-e^{im\pi}}$$
and use the fact
$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin(x)\quad;\quad e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1 + e^{im\pi}}{1 - e^{2im\pi}} = \dfrac{1}{1 - e^{im\pi}} = \dfrac{1}{1 - cos(m\pi) - i\cdot sin(m\pi)} = \dfrac{1}{2sin^2(m\frac{\pi}{2}) - i\cdot 2sin(m\frac{\pi}{2})cos(m\frac{\pi}{2})} = \dfrac{1}{2sin(m\frac{\pi}{2})}\cdot \dfrac{1}{sin(m\frac{\pi}{2}) - i\cdot cos(m\frac{\pi}{2})}$  $(1)$

$-i\cdot e^{im\frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{i\pi}\cdot e^{i(m+1)\frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{i(m+3)\frac{\pi}{2}} = cos((m+3)\frac{\pi}{2}) + i\cdot sin((m+3)\frac{\pi}{2}) = sin(m\frac{\pi}{2}) - i\cdot cos(m\frac{\pi}{2})$  $(2)$

Thus multiply  $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:

$LHS = \pi\cdot \dfrac{1}{2sin(m\frac{\pi}{2})} = \pi\cdot \dfrac{cos(m\frac{\pi}{2})}{sin(m\pi)} = RHS$